# Any platform macro of Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, macros

I'm newbie to Arduino. I'm making a cross-platform lib, I need to tell whether it's compiling to an Arduino, I searched but got nothing. Is there any predefined platform macro in the Arduino compiler, which I can tell I'm compiling to Arduino? Not only can be used in the main *.ino file, but also other *.c files under the scratch folder. Thanks.

Comment: Yes and if you google something like "arduino predefined macros" or "arduino predefined identifiers" you'll get a few useful links.

Comment: Recommendation: spin off special platform specific code to different  implementation files and let the build figure out which files to link in. That way you don't have to debug your way through mounds of conditional compilation.

Comment: Thank you guys. @CaptainObvlious I've tried similar searching but no result.

Comment: @user45813101 Nice choise, but this time it's an exception for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino headers define `ARDUINO`. The toolchain defines its own AVR- and ARM-specific defines, if you need to distinguish between those. See their documentation for details.

Comment: The ARDUINO works. Thank you for your quick and useful reply. BTW. I don't need to include any Arduino headers before checking the ARDUINO macro. Does it mean the toolchain will auto include some Arduino headers when compiling each compiling unit file, or the macro is defined within the toolchain itself?

Comment: The IDE preprocesses the .ino file to make it include the headers.